# Rails ransack not return all of records when there's no data that matches the parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

### I don't want to return all of the data when there's no data that matches the parameter so I want to return null instead.

As I know, ransack returns all of the data when there's no data that matches the parameter as default.
So do you have any idea to achieve that?

```
    @data = User.includes(:currencies).ransack(name_cont_any:%W(#{params[:q]})).result.uniq
```

Comment: I'm using the ransack method

Comment: why can't you check if `params[:q]` has no values and if so, don't call ransack?

Comment: @Anthony no the question is not based on the params. If the params has a value, but there isn't any record matching this value, Ransack returns by default all the records.

Comment: @Graham Slick Thank you for explaining my question. Since I'm not perfect in English, my question must have been confusing.
Sorry @ Anthony